# Empty protocol declarations

Tags: objective-c, protocols

The below protocol doesn't have any methods. Is it possible to use it like this? What happens if we declare an empty protocol?

```
@class CircularPickerView;
@protocol CircularPickerViewDataSource <UIPickerViewDataSource>
@end
```

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you're talking about. Is this Obj-C? C#? It's certainly not "html" or "title".

Comment: dont you know that @protocol belongs to objective c

Comment: No need to be cocky. I know that Obj-C has `@protocol`, but I don't know what other languages may have that keyword. Again, put it in the tags, otherwise the people that know Obj-C and could answer your question won't see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use it like this?

Yes.

> What happens if we declare an empty protocol?

Strictly, this is not empty - it is also a `UIPickerViewDataSource`. Similar to subclassing, you may pass `CircularPickerViewDataSource` as a `UIPickerViewDataSource`. You may also expect it to adopt `UIPickerViewDataSource`'s methods, and you will receive warnings if you do not implement the required interface. It may serve as documentation/intent, platform compatibility, or it may be a placeholder for future extension.

A protocol that declares no required or optional methods simply specifies adopters need not define any methods in their implementation. Since this is also a `UIPickerViewDataSource`, that's not exactly the case.